# How to render either a table or a graph selecting the option from a table

Tags: r, shiny, dt, shiny-reactivity

I have this minimum working example.

My goal is to select from the table an option of a table or a graph, and display it.

On the following approach, when you open the app, if you select table or graph it will be shown the first time.

```
## Only run examples in interactive R sessions
if (interactive()) {
  
  ui <- fluidPage(
    fluidRow(
      column(
        width = 4,
        DT::dataTableOutput("tableContents")
        ),
      column(
        width = 8,
        uiOutput("itemPreview")
      )
  
  )
  
  )
  
  server <- function(input, output) {
    
    menu <- reactive({
      objects <- c("Table1", "Plot1")
      menu <- data.frame(objects)
      menu
      
    })
    
    someData <- reactive({
      
      x <- c(1, 2, 3)
      y <- c(50, 20, 70)
      someData <- data.frame(x, y)
      someData
      
    })
    
    menuFun <- reactive({
      
      objects <- c("Table1", "Plot1")
      # functions <- c("table(someData())", "plot(someData())")
      functions <- c("table(someData())", "ggplot(someData(), (aes(x, y))) + geom_point()")
      menuFun <- data.frame(objects, functions)
      menuFun
      
    })
    
    output$tableContents <- DT::renderDataTable(menu(),
                                                options = list(dom = "t"),
                                                selection = list(mode = "single",
                                                                 target = "cell"),
                                                rownames = FALSE)
    
    observeEvent(input$tableContents_cells_selected, {
    
    objectSelection <- menu()[input$tableContents_cells_selected,]
    
    # objectSelection <- "Plot1"
    
    if (length(objectSelection) >= 1) {
    
      object <- eval(parse(text = menuFun() %>%
                             dplyr::filter(objects == objectSelection) %>%
                             dplyr::pull(functions)))
      
      if ("table" %in% class(object)) {
        
        output$tableContentSelection <- renderTable(object)
        output$itemPreview <- renderUI({
          
          tableOutput("tableContentSelection")
          
        })
        
      } else {
        
        output$tableContentSelection <- renderPlot(object)
        output$itemPreview <- renderUI({
          
          plotOutput("tableContentSelection")
          
        })
        
      } 
      
    }
    
  })
  
  }
  
  shinyApp(ui, server)
  
}
```

But when you select the other option, it doesn't update.

I want to keep selecting the option from the table since I will add many types of tables and graphs, and I find this approach more "dynamic".

Comment: Don't nest your reactives.  That simply doesn't work.  Create output objects using `renderPlot` and `renderTable` for the graph and table as normal.  Add a test that checks the value of `menuFun()`(?) and returns `NULL` rather than the plot/table if the other option is selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way of doing it.  There are easier ways of setting up the menu and rendering your graph and table, but I assume the reason for the complexity was hidden in creating your MWE.  As I wrote in my comment, your fundamental error was nesting your reactives.  Nesting them makes them local to your `observeEvent` and, since R's normal scoping rules apply, they are then not available to be monitored for updates by Shiny.

My solution creates a reactive with the current menu choice.  The `renderUI` then interrogates this reactive to determine which output widget is required.  The individual output widgets are defined at the same level as the `uiOutput`, inside the server function.

```
library(tidyverse)

ui <- fluidPage(
    fluidRow(
      column(
        width = 4,
        DT::dataTableOutput("tableContents")
      ),
      column(
        width = 8,
        uiOutput("itemPreview")
      )
    )
  )
  
  server <- function(input, output) {
    menu <- reactive({
      objects <- c("Table1", "Plot1")
      menu <- data.frame(objects)
      menu
    })
    
    someData <- reactive({
      data.frame(x=c(1, 2, 3), y=c(50, 20, 70))
    })
    
    menuFun <- reactive({
      objects <- c("Table1", "Plot1")
      # functions <- c("table(someData())", "plot(someData())")
      functions <- c("table(someData())", "ggplot(someData(), (aes(x, y))) + geom_point()")
      menuFun <- data.frame(objects, functions)
      menuFun
    })
    
    output$tableContents <- DT::renderDataTable(menu(),
                                                options = list(dom = "t"),
                                                selection = list(mode = "single",
                                                                 target = "cell"),
                                                rownames = FALSE)
    
    selectedObject <- reactive({
      objectSelection <- menu()[input$tableContents_cells_selected,]
      if (length(objectSelection) >= 1) {
        object <- eval(parse(text = menuFun() %>%
                               dplyr::filter(objects == objectSelection) %>%
                               dplyr::pull(functions)))
        object
      }
    })
    
    output$itemPreview <- renderUI({
      req(selectedObject())
      
      if (is(selectedObject(), "table")) {
        tableOutput("table")
      } else {
        plotOutput("plot")
      }
    })

    output$table <- renderTable({
      req(selectedObject())
      
      if (is(selectedObject(), "table"))selectedObject()
    })
    
    output$plot <- renderPlot({
      req(selectedObject())
      
      if (!is(selectedObject(), "table")) selectedObject()
    })
  }
  
  shinyApp(ui, server)
```